# Ubuntu booting into gnome not Unity

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome

First I have installed Gnome and removed unity. But now I want back unity. So I again installed unity and purged gnome. Problem is on booting it boots with gnome animation and before it i have a black screen which hangs for around 10sec. I want to get Unity booting back. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Logout and there will be a setting icon,you can select the the Unity from it.

Or

Try this command on terminal 'unity --replace'

Comment: I have purged gnome.... so it doesnt appear. Problem is i am getting unity but when booting i will get gnome animation....  not purple color

Comment: Try this command on terminal 'unity --replace'

Comment: Strange. GNOME should not affect Plymouth (the boot animation engine).

Comment: no it is not working @user3688259